# Best time to ask or answer

Tags: discussion

Is there like a best time during the day to answer or ask a question? In other words, when is there the most amount of users active who can respond and/or upvote your questions and answers?

Comment: Probably during day time in the USA. If day time lasts for 15 hours, then that makes a 18 hours period as the sun raises 3 hours earlier on the east coast than on the west coast (considering time zones and neglecting Main, New Brunswick, Puerto Rico and others as well as Alaska and of course Hawai). It is pretty wide. There are probably a faire amount of users from Europe and India as well. So... I wouldn't expect a special rush hour but real data might disagree with my guess.

Comment: And there are people from Australia too. Post whenever you want. If you think your post has not got attention you can post a link to it on the chat.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - Thanks for reminding folks of Down Under :) But quite frankly this country is next to empty. I do think US day time is the best time to go for rep.

Comment: No, the best time is clearly daytime in Canada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [blogpost by Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/the-best-time-to-ask-a-stack-overflow-question/) on exactly this. In it, he states:

> Looks like the most popular time to post is between 15:00 and 22:00 GMT/UTC, at least for all Stack Overflow data between launch and today.
>
> You'll have to convert those GMT hours to your local time zone, of course.
> For the USA, that's:
> Eastern Standard Time   GMT/UTC minus 5 hours
> Central Standard Time   GMT/UTC minus 6 hours
> Mountain Standard Time  GMT/UTC minus 7 hours
> Pacific Standard Time   GMT/UTC minus 8 hours

It is likely that the same times are relevant for BioSE as well, but might differ a bit depending on the specific user base here (e.g. where they are located).

There are also a couple of questions at Meta-SE on this:
[What is the best time to ask questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions)
[When's the best day and best time to post a question to Stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42572/whens-the-best-day-and-best-time-to-post-a-question-to-stackoverflow-com)